# Content security policy: source data

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, content-security-policy

I am setting up `Content security policy`. I have set up basic rules in report-only mode for testing.

I keep getting reports for blocked script but the source is only `data`:

```
 "csp-report": {
        "blocked-uri": "data",
        "document-uri": "http://www.example.com/page.html",
        "original-policy": "default-src http://www.example.com ...
        "violated-directive": "script-src 'unsafe-inline' http://www.example.com http://www.google-analytics.com;"
    }
```

I cannot reproduce the report even if I go to the same page with same browser type as visitor who caused this report. From `CSP` documentation I could not find anything about source called `data`.

The page `http://www.example.com/page.html` is mainly static html but has Google analytics script between `<script>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'...
</script>
```

The same script is used on other pages of my site including the frontpage. Yet only the page `page.html` generates these reports about blocked `data`.

What is this uri `data` that gets blocked? Is it something from my site or something external that the visitors browser tried to load?

Comment: See these a lot too. Suspect browser extensions. Really annoying as leads to a lot of noise in CSP reports denting their usefulness :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick question about the reports: do they happen across one browser or all?

**If only one browser:**
`script-src` violations with `blocked-uri: data` are likely noise from plugins. The pattern of loading javascript via data URLs *probably* aren't coming from you.

**If all browsers:**
If you aren't using the pattern, perhaps one of your libraries is. Google analytics does not use the pattern.

See https://twitter.com/Scott_Helme/status/710164802925142017 for a quick discussion.

Note: allowing `script-src data:` is very dangerous, or at least as dangerous as `'unsafe-inline'`. Source: http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2011/08/simulate-script-injection-via-data-uri.html

Comment: The reports are mostly caused by Firefox and a few cases of Chrome. But only by some users of those browsers. Since `script-src data:` is so risky I will avoid allowing it. (And hopefully get rid of `unsafe inline` soon).

Comment: That's great! I see you've already disallowed eval. If you'd like some tips on removing the inline script, I wrote this years ago: http://oreoshake.github.io/csp/2013/01/13/removing-inline-js-for-csp.html

Comment: I've found Google Analytics causing data-uri blocking messages ... I wonder if there's a way to specify which sources are allowed to do data-uri and which aren't?

Comment: Never mind, I suspect it was caused by this async downloading script: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ I'll try a different approach to loading GA...

Comment: Actually, it was this: http://icompile.eladkarako.com/you-cant-really-adblock-google-analytics-on-chrome/ -- but it's not as it seems. This isn't sent by Google...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945501/307-redirect-when-loading-analytics-js-in-chrome for instructions on how to determine which Chrome plugin is causing this and https://gist.github.com/eddywashere/fbd3a79104dfb1fbb971 for an example of uBlock Origin's.