# Default 307 redirect http - https | Nginx, let's encrypt, Google Cloud, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: redirect, nginx, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-16.04, lets-encrypt

On Google Cloud i set up:

1. Ubuntu 16.04 Server
2. Nginx
3. let's encrypt

The Server redirects all http Requests per default 307 redirect to https. In the sites-available config i dont see a 307 configuration.

**I really dont know where this configuration is set?**

The better way is to use a 301 instead of a 307.

Comment: I noticed the same thing. Have you found an answer?

Comment: @WaldoJeffers sadly no answer belong this question.

Comment: I had the same issue, and found out what caused this. It was actually completeley unrelated to nginx. The 307 redirect is done by Chrome. First, you'll want to check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945501/307-redirect-when-loading-analytics-js-in-chrome) which will help you identify what exactly is causing the redirection.  In my case, I followed a tutorial on how to setup Let's Encrypt, which recommended to activate [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), which forces the browser to connect in HTTPS, on *all* subdomains.