# Azure web.config Permanent redirection and get 307 status code instead of 301

Tags: redirect, web-config, azure-web-app-service, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-307

I'm trying to redirect all http traffic to https while returning 301 status code. For some reason, I get 307 status instead and I dont know why. I tried to search to see if I missed something in my config, but it's seem similar to everything I saw.

My web.config

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="ForceWWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^MY_DOMAINE" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.MY_DOMAINE/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

I just found something interesting. Exemple my domaine is domaine.com

If I search:

domaine.com the redirection is 301

http://www.domaine.com the redirection is 307

www.domaine.com the redirection is 307

**UPDATE**

I only got the problem with Chrome. Other browers have the 301 status with the redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify the Strict_Transport_Security in the response, which activates [HSTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security)

Chrome doesn't even call the server and redirects directly through a 307 http code. [More info](https://www.seroundtable.com/googlebot-hsts-redirects-301-307-21405.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to your web.config, you specified redirectType="Permanent", it should return 301 status code.
You can check if the same behavior is reproducible in other browsers as well.

Comment: I just tried in other browsers and i got 301 status. Is there anything special with Chrome??

Comment: I am not very sure about chrome's behavior. You can check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945501/307-redirect-when-loading-analytics-js-in-chrome